# What is the best practice of running cron job in a docker container

Tags: linux, cron, docker

My application is a Python Django running on a docker container.This application has a cron job that keeps updating the data in a database. Should I put this cron job into a separate container because I read some documents mentioning that I should redirect to cron job output to the docker console. Is there any best practice on running cron on a container?

Answer (score 3):

Creating a Docker container in order to execute jobs to other containers is a good practice, If You have a separate container for databases and one for your Django application, it would be a good practice to have a separate docker container running for cron jobs, as with the time your project might grow and you would have a centralized crontab by that time ready to be used. As how to do it there is a nice article describing how to do this:
[Creating a Docker container in order to execute jobs to other containers](https://juliendubreuil.fr/blog/devops/creating-docker-container-to-execute-jobs-to-other-containers/)

Comment: This link provides some good info on running a cronjob in the container.

Comment: This link shows a 404 now